# why @output not working in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am trying send data from one component to another in angular 2 . my `@output is not working`.I am adding item in list .On click of `row` . I am sending data from one component to another.
here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/sG6Suhnvc3Qmjmqjym67?p=preview

I do like this,

```
 @Output() userUpdated = new EventEmitter();

liClick(item){
      this.userUpdated.emit(item)
  }
```

**this is not fired why ?**

```
 userSelected(items){
    alert(items);
    this.title="user is selected" +item.name;
  }
```

Comment: where is `liClick` called?

Comment: right @suraj, where is liClick called?

Comment: by mistake I will change pluker version

Comment: see update https://plnkr.co/edit/sG6Suhnvc3Qmjmqjym67?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/4zIzOsjiP3WdRj8EayKe?p=preview you had a typo in your function `userSelected(item){
    this.title="user is selected" +item.name;
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing event binding `userUpdated` should be inside `( )` brackets

```
<app-home [userItems]="items" (userUpdated)="userSelected($event)"></app-home>
```

And you had some typo errors.

[**Updated plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y9dXxCzIl1pq7WnaMLTl?p=preview)

Update 1 : you had a typo there `item.name` was there in your plunker

```
 this.title="user is selected" +items.name;
```

Comment: not working ..! title not changed https://plnkr.co/edit/sG6Suhnvc3Qmjmqjym67?p=preview

Comment: yes ...function is called ..but inside body i write this     this.title="user is selected" +item.name;  title should change change

Comment: @user5711656, it's your typo of using item instead of items in userSelected function