# angular2: dynamically add inputs for an array of items

Tags: angular, focus, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I've got a `User` entity in my system. Each user has a mail email (not relevant here) and an `alternateEmails` property which is an array of strings (to have more multiple less important emails).

I need to create a form that will have the main email displayed always - and will have all alternate emails - 1 input for each alternate email. And a button `add email`. Pretty standard interface thing in UI.

This is what I have now:

`user-form.component.html`:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let ae of user.alternateEmails; let i = index">
    <label for="alternateEmail{{i}}">alternate email {{i}}:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="alternateEmail{{i}}" id="alternateEmail{{i}}" placeholder="alternate email" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.alternateEmails[i]" />
</div>

<button (click)="addAlternateEmailClicked()">add email</button>
```

`user-form.component.ts`:

```
addAlternateEmailClicked(){
  this.user.alternateEmails.push('');
}
```

It displays data very well. When I load data from the server, it reflects the number of alternate emails the user has (displays none if there were none, displays 2 if there were 2, etc):

[image]

When I click `add email`, new input appears:

[image]

**The crazy problem** I'm facing is that when I focus on a given alternate email (click inside the input, so that I can start writing), I can type only one char - and the input loses focus. I get no idea why is focus/blur working behind the scenes. Perhaps it has something to do with angular magic.

I'd appreciate (1) how to change the code to make it usable :) (no loosing focus on dynamic inputs) and (2) explanation on why is current solution wrong.

Comment: [**Refer this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224772/why-output-not-working-in-angular-2) which has a demo.

Comment: @Aravind this exact demo is unrelated to dynamic input insertion. What do you mean?

Comment: are you sure that is diffferent from your expectation

Comment: @Aravind look at the screenshots. You've got just items displayed, I've got inputs to receive user input. Can you see a difference?

Comment: If I were you I'd switch to FormBuilder and use a FormArray instead, a normal form doesn't really support array-like data like this is. Would probably solve the issue too.

Comment: Have you tried using [(ngModel)]="ae" instead of [(ngModel)]="user.alternateEmails[i]" ?

Comment: Maybe a plunkr would help for debugging.

Comment: I may be late, but all you need is a custom `trackBy` function. Put a `trackBy: myCustomTB` in your *ngFor, and in your component, add a function with two optional parameters (obviously called MyCustomTB), and that returns the first one. You the&#39; should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution instead:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

public userForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  emails: this.fb.array([])
});
```

Swap `ngModel` for `formControlName`:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let email of userForm.emails.controls; let i = index">
    <label [for]="i">Alternative email {{i}}:</label>
    <input class="form-control" [id]="i" placeholder="Alternative email" type="text" formControlName="email">
</div>

<button (click)="addAlternateEmailClicked()">add email</button>
```

Push a new control to the form array:

```
addAlternateEmailClicked(){

  const emails: FormArray = <FormArray>this.userForm.get('emails');

  // Validators is optional
  emails.push(this.fb.control('', Validators.required));
}
```

Comment: I guess that heavy angular built0in solutions can manage this out of the box. I was hoping that there might be a more light-weight approach to deal with it. Especially that, in my scenario, everything works fine - only except for this focus/blur...

Comment: @ducin I think the issue is that you're trying to bind to a dynamic `ngModel`, which doesn't really work all that well unless you're doing it with this approach. It could feed some unexpected bugs sometimes. I think that if you try FormBuilder you'll never go back, it's really neat and powerful.